# MySQL - many to many table - primary keys and duplicates

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

Let's assume we have two tables: products and orders. As it is a multi-to-many relationship, I've created an extra table: ordersproducts.

As I read from many threads, two primary keys are recommended in this case - table ordersproducts:

order_id (PK), product_id (PK, FK),

However, in this situation there can't be duplicates in the table. Order_id can be duplicated, but product_id has to be unique, and I need a bit more flexibility - order_id should be able to duplicate and so should product_id.

Works correctly after removing the primary keys, leaving only the foreign key at product_id, however - table without primary keys doesn't seem right, does it?

Comment: you can make unique of combination of (order_id  and product_id)  In this case order_id   can be duplicate same goes for product_id but both can't duplicate at same time

Comment: The thing is - I need them both be able to duplicate at same time. In one order can be i.e. 4 products: keyboard, mouse, mouse, sdd drive. (It's just an example.) And mouse can't be solved as a quantity, product mouse in this case is more like a type of product than exact product.

Comment: in that case have 3 column in ordersproducts 1. primary key 2,3 order_id and product_id

Comment: Is it just for a performance while browsing table or something else?

Comment: this is to fulfill your condition and format for a mysql table which says one field must be primary key .....

Comment: Ok, I got it :-) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Always have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It sounds like you need either (*not both*) of these:

```
PRIMARY KEY(order_id, product_id)
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, order_id)
```

These say (because a MySQL PK must be unique) that there *may* be duplicates of either column, but the *pair* is never duplicates.

Since you probably want to go both directions (given an order, find all the products *and* given a product, find all the orders), you need indexes both ways:

```
PRIMARY KEY(order_id, product_id),
INDEX(product_id, order_id)
```

Remember, a PK is UNIQUE and is an INDEX.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) are more tips on virtually any many:many table.  That discusses a generic solution to your generic problem.